# Get lat lng of full address and suburb in one hit using Google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am currently using Google maps Autocomplete. Works great, I can get the lat and lng of the full address as I need.

However, I would like to get the lat lng of the suburb/postcode of that full address, all in one hit. How?
My code is 99% identical to the [Google Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms), only changing html elements ids and stuff

```
<script>
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.countryLatitude, @Model.countryLongitude),
            zoom: 3,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          mapOptions);
        // create a marker
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.9167, 79.8473);

        var input = document.getElementById('fullAddress');
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            fillInAddress();
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            //input.className = '';                
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
                input.className = 'notfound';
                return;
            }                
            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(15);
            }
            marker.setIcon(({
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
            }));
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);
        })
    }
    // [START region_fillform]
    function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.            
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        document.getElementById('latitude').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('longitude').value = place.geometry.location.lng();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            //document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    }
    // [END region_fillform]
    // [START region_geolocation]
    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
    function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
                    geolocation));
            });
        }
    }
    // [END region_geolocation]
</script>
```

Comment: show your response handling code and give better explanation of what you need it to do

Comment: I just edited the question. Apart from the latitude and longitude for the full address, I need the latitude and longitude of the suburb that belongs to the full address

Comment: you would need to make a different request based on results of first request

Comment: so there is no way to get all on the same request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution, not ideal, but it works.

Once I fill in the suburb and postcode fields from the google autocomplete feature, I need to make another request using this url:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SUBURB,%20POSTCODE%20AND%20COUNTRY%20HERE&components=administrative_area:SUBURB%7Ccountry:COUNTRY

with this, I can get the longitude and latitude of the suburb too.